# How do I use puppeteer to take full screenshots of several websites?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, browser-automation

I am trying to take a screenshot using Node.js with [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer). I am not using [`page.screenshot()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.18.1/docs/api.md#pagescreenshotoptions) because the screenshot needs to contain the entire desktop. Instead, I am screenshotting with ImageMagick's [`import`](https://imagemagick.org/script/import.php) command.

My current code works most of the time. But other times, it fails with strange results, such as:

- The tab is switched, but the screenshot contains half of the old page.
- The page is switched but blank.
- Adding a delay works but is not ideal, because sometimes page loading is very slow.

The problem seems to be that [`page.bringToFront()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.18.0/docs/api.md#pagebringtofront) does not wait for the page to load fully.

I am new to both Node and puppeteer. Please suggest a way to:

1. Load a page in Chrome.
2. Switch to the page once loaded.
3. Take a screenshot of the desktop by executing a command-line tool.

Adding a delay to the code does not seem to be the best solution.

Any suggestion on code improvement would be helpful.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
const sleep = require('sleep'); 

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: [
            '--ignore-certificate-errors',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-infobars',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            '--incognito',
            '--window-size=1600,1200',
            '--start-maximized',
            "--disable-gpu"],
        // slowMo: 250, // slow down by 1550ms
    });

    await browser.newPage();
    await browser.newPage();
    const pages = await browser.pages();
    await Promise.all([
        grabpage(pages[0], 'https://www.cnn.com', 'cnn'),
        grabpage(pages[1], 'https://www.bbc.com', 'bbc'),
        grabpage(pages[2], 'https://www.rediff.com', 'rediff'),
    ]);
    // Someday we will close the browser also.
})();

async function grabpage(page, url, path) {
    await page.goto(url);
    var infront =page.bringToFront();
    infront.then(
        sleep.sleep(5),
        execSync('import -window root ' + path +'.jpg'),
    );
    console.log('took Screenshot: '+path+'.jpg')
}
```

[Rediff page not loaded fully without sleep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmRnF.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You're making it all confusing by trying to run everything in parallel with `Promise.all`. Because you have only one instance of `browser`, when you run `grabpage` 3 times in parallel, they're all competing for control over browser and can get in between each other's `await`s.

I would also suggest that you open and close individual pages in `grabpage`. You'd have to switch it to pass `browser` in and do `const page = await browser.newPage();`

so you end up with

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      args: [
            '--ignore-certificate-errors',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-infobars',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            '--incognito',
            '--window-size=1600,1200',
            '--start-maximized',
            "--disable-gpu"],
      //      slowMo: 250, // slow down by 1550ms
    });

    await grabpage(browser, 'https://www.cnn.com', 'cnn'),
    await grabpage(browser, 'https://www.bbc.com', 'bbc'),
    await grabpage(browser, 'https://www.rediff.com', 'rediff'),
})();

async function grabpage(browser, url, path) {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  execSync('import -window root ' + path +'.jpg')
  // await page.screenshot({path: `${path}.png`}); //if you just need to take a screenshot, not the whole desktop
  await page.close();
}
```

not sure why you need to take the full desktop, though if you `start-maximized`. i guess you care about the tiny bit of OS chrome that you get in the screenshot.

Comment: OP mentioned in the question "I am not using `page.screenshot()` as screenshot has to contain complete desktop. The screen is taken using imagemagick `import` command which can take a screenshot."

Comment: yeah, my bad, i missed the part where OP says he doesn't want `page.screenshot` but the approach suggested should work with imagemagic, too. His confusion is caused by loading all pages at once and then having to switch between them.

Comment: updated answer to address comment posted by @MultiplyByZer0

Comment: He's doing a lot worse than that. There's also the fact that he's using a hacky C++ npm module named [`sleep`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep) instead of `setTimeout()`, he's using `child_process.execSync()` in an asynchronous function, and he forgot to wrap his code to `infront.then()` in an arrow function. And your updated answer looks good.

Comment: @Anderi R, Thanks for your reply. Few things I should have mentioned loading one URL per page slows down the process. So I wanted to have all tabs load at the same time. I ran the code few times but the page is not completely loaded.  https://imgur.com/9F3q8GY   https://imgur.com/3qMwchc  https://imgur.com/aS2PK7N .. The reason I added a Hacky sleep :)

Comment: @Chakra you need to get it to work before you worry about making it fast.

Comment: I found that it's not enough to `await page.goto`. it's best to wait for a particular selector on a page that indicates that everything has finished loading.

Comment: Agreed .. I have added ...  await page.goto(url, { waitNetworkIdle: true , timeout: 120000,},{ waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' } .. but nothing much .. I am looking for a way to  have command execute on tab once loaded and make all code wait for command to complete.

Comment: @Chakra Try `await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "load" });`.

Comment: Not much luck with adding waitUntil .. I am trying to see page.evaluate and check some component on the page. Only thing is I dont have all the URLs which I would check so hard to know whats on the page.

Comment: @Chakra don't be afraid to ask more questions on SO regarding this. Please don't expand the question to turn it into a complete solution for your project.